# trouble installing package: ecogbm

Tags: r

I have downloaded a package from here:

[ecogbm](http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/Ecology/ecogbm_1.01.tar.gz)

I tried to install it like this:

```
setwd("d:/RStuff")
install.packages("ecogbm_1.01.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Unfortunately I get this:

```
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users/Bla/Documents/R/win-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'ecogbm' ...
** Creating default NAMESPACE file
** libs

*** arch - i386
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'ecogbm'
* removing 'C:/Users/Bla/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/ecogbm'
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.0/bin/x64/R CMD INSTALL -l         "C:/Users/Bla/Documents/R/win-library/2.15"   "ecogbm_1.01.tar.gz"' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("ecogbm_1.01.tar.gz", type = "source", repos = NULL) :
   installation of package ‘ecogbm_1.01.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status`
```

I am not sure whether the `i386` means anything. I run the 64bit R version. Is my installation process flawed or can someone please verify that there is something wrong with this package? Is there another way to get it installed? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the impression that you are trying to install a source package on Windows without the appropriate source-building tools available to you. If this is the case then you need to either obtain a binary from somewhere or build one yourself. Details on how to set up the tool chain required can be found in the [R Windows FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html) and the [R installation and Administration manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html)

If you don't fancy setting up the toolchain yourself, you can make use of the excellent WinBuilder server maintained by Uwe Ligges. See the [relevant section](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#How-can-I-get-a-binary-version-of-a-package_003f) of the R Windows FAQ for details and the site which is here: http://win-builder.r-project.org/

Do note the point about the package being known to work on an UNIX-alike; given the **ecogbm** is a beta package there may well be problems building it even on UNIX-alikes which will most likely mean the Windows binary can not be built either.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it myself but get: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status. Must be some c++ related stuff. Any idea?

Comment: @csetzkorn It compiles/installs for me on Fedora Linux. Perhaps you should submit it to the win builder service I mention and see if they can get it to build. After that, you'd have to go back to Trevor Hastie for help/advice. He may be aware of such issues and that may explain why this is not on CRAN but on his publications page.

Comment: I submitted it. I unpacked it and changed Maintainer in the DESCRIPTION file and tar-ed it using cygwin. I have not yet heard back. I presume I get an email? Thanks.

Comment: @csetzkorn yes, you will but it can take a wee while - it will go into a queue (the same system builds the binaries for CRAN as far as I can tell) so it just depends how often they pick-up new packages and start a build run off. Either way you'll get an email telling you it worked and how to get your binary or it should contain the check logs that might help in tracking down the problem.

Comment: I submitted it Friday and still did not receive anything. Is this normal?

Comment: @csetzkorn I don't know - I've only ever used it once to do a pre-submission check to CRAN. I'd give it another day or so and then contact the maintainer of that service.