# Install and build an R package in windows from a tar.gz

Tags: r, linux, windows

I have built an R package in Linux, it compiles perfectly, and generates a tar.gz file, installable and executable.

Now I am trying to build the windows version of my library with the RTools (last version) following the instructions of this page:

https://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~kbroman/Rintro/Rwinpack.html

When I execute the following command:

```
R CMD INSTALL --build --compile-both mypackage.tar.gz
```

I got the error:

```
Warning in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) :
  failed to copy 'rbdd/libs/libbuddy.so.0.0.0' to 'rbdd/libs/libbuddy.so'
Warning in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) :
  restoring symbolic link as a file copy
* installing to library 'C:/Users/Sergio/Documents/R/win-library/3.3'
* installing *binary* package 'mypackage' ...
cp: unknown option -- )
Try '/usr/bin/cp --help' for more information.
Warning: executed command 'cp -R . "C:/Users/Sergio/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/mypackage" || ( tar cd - .| (cd "C:/Users/Sergio/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/mypackage" && tar -xf -))' has status 1
ERROR: installing binary package failed
* removing 'C:/Users/Sergio/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/mypackage'
```

I have configured my Path variable as follows:

```
PATH:C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.0\bin\x64\;...;C:\Windows\system32;...
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: have you tried installing it from the menu? and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320882/installation-of-r-package-tar-gz-in-windows?rq=1)? I may be wrong but if you have an executable that should work?

Comment: I you are not committed to developing the resources to do this on your own then the winbuilder facility is available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449048/trouble-installing-package-ecogbm/10449209?s=1|0.8206#10449209